# Creating shopify scripttag in python

Tags: javascript, python, localhost, shopify, shopify-api

I'm developing a python app for Shopify which creates a scripttag to display some content on the storefront. Now, I'm confused that the python server file is running on localhost and I'm able to test it using ngrok. How can I make the scripttag.js file run in the same project as well? I tried to host the js file on google drive for testing purposes but it gave me CORB error. So, where exactly should the js file go as I want to run it inside the python project?
[CORB Error in the browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Il0JA.png)

Comment: Hi, Try keeping your script file in a public directory in your server structure and then use ngrok to add it to the store. Another thing if you are calling the script tag API directly from the front-end then it won't let you add the js file in the store and you will always get the CORB error. You need to create an endpoint on your server which then calls the script tag API endpoint to add the script file.